# Is it allowed to use Data retrieved from an Instagram Basic Display API App in Development Mode for production purposes?

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

My use case is fairly simple: I want do display the latest images of an Instagram profile I own on a public website I own.

For this purpose I've written an integration of the Instagram Basic Display API, registered an app with https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, implemented an automated access token renewal mechanism and everything works locally.

So, as I'm about to publish this feature to the website, I'm not able to find any official policy from Facebook that clearifies whether or not I'm required to put this app in "Live Mode".

Technically, "Live Mode" has no benefits to my use case and I'd find it way out of proportion to go through an App Review process, just to display a list of images that are my own anyway. So my question is:

**Given this scenario, is it allowed to keep said App in "Development Mode", while still using its data for production purposes?**

And: Are there any official statements on this, that any of you might be aware of and that I'm just not able to find?

I found this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2019/09/23/live-mode-for-production-use/

But even though the headline is fairly unambiguous, the article itself doesn't help making the issue any clearer...

Comment: If what you are trying to achieve here _works_ for you while still in dev mode, then I guess it should probably be okay. The main purpose of the review process, to me, appears to be to protect other users, from apps using their data in abusive ways. But if you are the only app user, then you could only “abuse” your own data here to begin with. Whether Facebook might shut your app down at some point, if they find out the data gets publicly used elsewhere, is hard to say. If you want to be absolutely sure that won’t happen, then you should rather get it properly reviewed, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to use Development mode in such case: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/introduction

> If your app will only be used by app users who have a role on the app or claimant Business, App Review is not required and your app does not need to be switched to Live mode.